# How do i import/use an image in my python code? preferably without an external module

Tags: python

My code is this and im trying to make a coin flipper
(The code might look weird because i recycled the script from a random joke selector i coded)

```
coinside = ['heads.png',
            'tales.png',]
from random import randint
def pick(words):
    num_words = len(words)
    num_picked = randint(0, num_words - 1)
    word_picked = words[num_picked]
    return word_picked
print(pick(coinside))
while True:
    print(pick(coinside))
    input()
```

Comment: What do you want to do with this image? Is your goal to display it on a GUI?

Comment: There are no built-in Python modules that deal with images.  You're going to need `pillow`.  Why do you even care about external modules?  They are THERE to be used.

Comment: @green i just want it to show up on the windows command prompt when i run the code so if i press enter it shows a coin side that was chosen at random

Comment: @Tim Roberts I have a hard time working with them and there are so many places to download pillow but i haven't seen a version for python 3.9 but if i have to use it i will

Comment: Don't search for and download it yourself.  Do `pip install pillow`.  `pip` knows where to find the current approved version of virtually all modules.

Comment: You can't show an image at a command prompt.  You can show the image NAME.  Is that all you want?

Comment: Well, ASCII art is also some kind of image, I guess. @SpeedyGuy Please inform yourself about `pip` and virtual environments or, alternatively, anaconda. They make working with external libraries usually very easy.

Comment: @green thanks for your help i realized to install pillow i had to use the pip function IN the cmd prompt i feel very stupid now there is only one thing how do i make it randomly choose between the 2 images and show which ever one was picked?

Comment: Please refer to @TimRoberts answer, instead of strings, you'd just put image objects into the list. A description on how to use pillow to load images and display images is only a Google search away.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is a command-line coin flipper, you don't need that much code.

```
import random
coins = ['heads', 'tails']
while True:
    print(random.choice(coins))
    input()
```

Answer (score -1):

Since it is impossible to do this without external modules, if you want to work with images in python you need pillow.

you can find more information here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/working-images-python/